# Changing network interface will cause cassandra node fail?

Tags: networking, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a dse-cassandra cluster for use in production. I would like to attach an network-interface to every node. If I add the ip address of that interface on each cassandra config; would it break the cluster?